# How to fix UITableView Accessibility speak in wrong languge while scrolling?

Tags: ios, iphone, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm creating an app in Polish (Polish is set in iPhone settings). All VoiceOver text are said in Polish (like button, numbers etc.).

But when I scroll UITableView with three fingers it say in English: "Rows 1 to 10 of 16" (1, 10 and 16 in Polish).

How to fix it?

---

**EDIT:**

It speaks "Rows %d to %d of %d" in English with Polish accent.

What is interesting is that, in system's apps like Contacs, while scrolling, it says "Rows %d to %d of %d" in whole Polish.

Comment: Interesting case; UITableView uses a custom accessibility implementation, and likely uses one of the notification APIs to tell VoiceOver to read out that string in response to scrolling: it sounds as though it's using a template string ("Rows %d to %d of %d") that hasn't itself been localized. The speech synth does its best to treat that string as Polish, so reads out the textual numbers correctly - "10" will get turned into the appropriate Polish word - but likely ends up just pronouncing the other words as-is, perhaps with a bit of a Polish accent? Wonder if there's any way to verify this...

Comment: Do you know if this happens in other languages? For example, Spanish?

Comment: Does the same issue reproduce in a new project and only a plain table view without any customization (other than some rows of data, so that you can scroll)?

Comment: @BrendanMcK Yes, it speaks "Rows %d to %d of %d" in English with Polish accent.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist In new project, with only UITableView, it behaves the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

In xcode, in project settings, Info tab, there is a [Localization section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r7hf.png). And there was no Polish localization, becouse we didn't localized app (app only in Polish). I click +, add Polish localization, and now it say "Rows %d to %d of %d" totally in Polish.